# How to use If condition in calculated filed of excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate Growth% through calculated filed in Excel, however I am not able get the desired output specified in **Column I**.

I used the following formula in the calculated filed i.e. `"='Year 2020' /'Year 2019'-1"`and it is coming correctly where I have the data in the months (i.e. 1 to 4), however for future months (i.e. 5 to 12) it is showing -100% as there is no data in Column B for those months.

Is it possible to create a IF condition in the calculated field which will show data only for the months which have data and for those -100% months should show as blank cell (without any data) like **Column I**.  I tried If condition in excel worksheet, please refer **Column K** which is working fine only in the worksheet :(

In the below image:

1) **Data** in Columns **A** to **C**

2) **Pivot table** in Columns **F** to **G**

3) My **desired output** in Column **I**

4) Formula that I have used to get the desired output which is working only in the worksheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you required to do a pivot for this method?  If not, a simple formula table will do the trick.
Can add a table and fill in the rows with the formula outlook as such

Month  Growth
1       Formula

```
=IF(B3="","",IF(B3/C3-1=-1,"",(B3/C3)-1)
```

Comment: Yes, I need to use the formula in the pivot calculated field, so that I can use slicers to change the views dynamically.

Comment: I tried all possible other options to add in calculated field of a PivotTable and figured out that it is not possible, hence I believe this is the only option I also can think of at the movement.  Thank you so much.